# Export to CSV and sort in columns by Station

Tags: mysql

How to export in CSV in two or more columns and sort by Stations, from left to right ? Not in line one below the other, like this:

```
SELECT Station, Datee, Valuee
FROM ddtemperatura
WHERE (Station='14542' OR Station='14668') AND Datee BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2008-01-31'
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Output\\Srednja6.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY'"' TERMINATED BY',' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

It should look like this:

```
"14542","2008-01-27 00:00:00","5.2","14668","2008-01-01 00:00:00","0.5"

"14542","2008-01-28 00:00:00","2.6","14668","2008-01-02 00:00:00","-0.7"

"14542","2008-01-29 00:00:00","1.5","14668","2008-01-03 00:00:00","0.2"

"14542","2008-01-30 00:00:00","2.9","14668","2008-01-04 00:00:00","4.7"

"14542","2008-01-31 00:00:00","3.7","14668","2008-01-05 00:00:00","8.2"
```

Comment: Have you tried to add an `ORDER BY Station` to the query

Comment: Yes, that not help. It should be from left to right by Station.